# How to copy files containing | in the name?

Tags: windows-7, filenames

In Windows 7 I can't copy the file with `|` in the name. Gives me an error `Can not find the file`. I have around 30GB of files and all contains that character. Any idea how can I copy them to another NTFS partition?

Comment: How did you create those files in the first place?

Comment: Downloaded from torrents.

Comment: Do you still have the torrent? If you do, use the torrent client and move the storage, since it obviously can handle these improper file names.

Comment: Nop, unfortunately I don't have such torrent registered anymore, neither I have Linux to move those files(I remember I moved them from Ubuntu to Windows 7 partition).

Comment: mounting the drives with a linux liveCD/USB would be a quick and clean solution, but I wonder if there's a way to do it from just windows? I just tried making a file with | in it from my linux machine on my windows machine and it yelled at me. Downloading from a running https server on my netbook didn't work either, it changed the | to a -. Maybe try moving them with the command prompt and shortnames? `dir /x` will list shortnames that you can use.

Comment: "Gives me an error". What does? Explorer? CMD.EXE? XCOPY?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Command Line is your friend.

Open a `CMD` and `CD` to the location of the files.

Enter `dir /X` and this will show you the old DOS 8.3 names with `~1`, `~2` etc alongside the long filename.

You can then copy/rename using the 8.3 names

You can mix 8.3 and long filenames when renaming:

`ren THISIS~1.TXT "this is renamed.txt"` will work

[image]

Comment: Love this idea, as long as the filename is over 8 characters. It's the first windows solution I thought of.

Comment: @Rob even if the filename is less than 8 chars I believe it will give an alternative to use in this case where there are illegal chars, It's a bit difficult to test tho!

Comment: I wonder if you can do the same thing with the filename quoted.  i.e. ren "file|name" filename

Comment: @MattH I don't _think_ so as it is still an illegal character for a Windows filename. Again, very hard to test as it is difficult to create files with that character in the filename!

Answer (score 4):

The `\\?\` prefix tells Windows that your path is perfectly fine and that you don't want anything done to it. That does mean it's less forgiving. E.g. `dir "\\?\C:"` doesn't work. The proper path is `dir "\\?\C:\"`.

This should help you bypass the restriction on using `|` in NTFS filenames. However, you should still quote the filename so that CMD.EXE doesn't interpret the `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid characters in file name will cause problems rather sooner than later. I'd recommend you rename all the files to avoid further issue.

This should work (but it's untested):

1. Download [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and burn a Live CD.
2. Boot from the Live CD.
3. Open a terminal, go to the folder containing the odd files and exexcute

   ```
   find . | grep "|" | awk '{ OLD=$0; gsub(/\|/, "_"); print "mv \"" OLD "\" \"" $0 "\"" }' | sh
   ```

That should replace all `|`s with `_`s.

Comment: I know there's an easier way to do it than with awk, but that should work. Let me ssh into my linux machine and see if it's still in my bash history.

Comment: @Rob: Feel free to improve it. I pretty much use `awk` for everything.

Comment: for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | tr '|' '_')" ; done

Comment: @Rob: That **is** easier. I've changed it a little so it works with subdirectories and doesn't print error message when source and destination are identical.

Comment: change it to `for f in "$(find . | grep '|')";` or it'll mess up with files with spaces.

Comment: Love the idea that you have to download another operating system to fix windows.

Comment: @Rob: That doesn't work either. The quotes cause `for` to see only a single file name. Back to square one...

Comment: Are you sure? It worked great for me with debian testing.

Comment: nevermind, I used ls | grep, awk to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest the same thing as Dennis. There are many apps [available for windows](http://lifehacker.com/5139592/ant-renamer-is-a-lightweight-but-powerful-renaming-utility) as well, but I don't know how well they would do renaming files with an "invalid" character.